# How do I extract data from a Java object?

Tags: java, object, data-structures, tf-idf

I am C programmer and now I moved to Java. I am trying to convert C program in Java program. C programs simply calculate term frequency and inverse document frequency ([tf/idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)).

I created one data class

```
public class Data {
    private String fileName,fileText;
    private int fileId;
    private float value;

    public void addData(String fileName, String fileText, float value){
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileText = fileText;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getFileId(){
        return this.fileId;
    }


    public String getFileName(){
        return this.fileName;
    }

    public String getFileText(){
        return this.fileText;
    }

    public float getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

This class is responsible to store file name, file text, and Value (tf value or idf value).

The following class is responsible to store data:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, Data> map = new HashMap<String, Data>();
        Data dt = new Data();

        dt.addData("abc.txt", "some contents", 2);
        map.put("1",dt);
        dt.addData("w", "some more contents in second file", 3);
        map.put("2",dt);

        System.out.println(map);

    }

}
```

When I print map, it gives me some weird values. I think, I have to declare array of data class? I don't  know how many files are there, therefore I can not put any static array number.

Also, how can I calculate TF and IDF based on this data structure?

In a C program, I simply read files, count the words divide by total number of words to get TF and a word divided by total occurrence of that word in all files to get IDF. I do not know how to do it using above data structure.

I get weird values. Maybe these are objects:

```
{2=test2.Data@19821f, 1=test2.Data@19821f}
```

Is there any way to get a specific value from Data class using `getFileName` etc. functions?

Comment: Rather than saying the `println()` "gives me some weird values", perhaps you could show what output you *do* get. Most Java programmers can guess what you're seeing, but it's good to be sure. Your weird values might be perfectly normal to another reader.

Comment: The core of your question appears to be "When I print map, it gives me some weird values". What were you expecting, vs what you got?

Comment: Your main class has a bug that's somewhat an aside from your question. You are attempting to insert the same Data instance into your map multiple times. You might be surprisd to know that the second call to addData will actually result in an overwrite of the values already inserted into the map. Instead, call new Data() prior to each addData statement.

Comment: Here are the values {2=test2.Data@19821f, 1=test2.Data@19821f} and I think these are objects. I am sorry for calling it weird values. I want to print all the values that I added in Data class object. And any idea for second question?

Comment: Beware of using the same object ( is like using the same struct ) because you're just dropping the previous values.

Answer (score 1):

For question one, unless you override `toString()`, you are unlikely to get any meaningful output just by printing objects directly to stdout. The 'test2.Data@19821f' is what `Object.toString()` returns - class name followed by object hash. In this case, it quite helpfully shows that both your values are the same objects.

You can open/read files using `java.io.File` and `java.io.FileInputStream`. A map from strings to integers `java.util.Map<String,Integer>` will probably help with counting words in those files.

There doesn't seem to be much need for your data class for this simple application. You've already described the algorithm to follow, it's just a case of writing it in Java syntax.

Welcome to the wonderful world of type safety and not worrying about memory leaks.

Comment: Could you please explain bit more, what do you mean by I can do it only with File reader? I just searched good to see any example, but I couldn't find any :(

Comment: If you are trying to write an application to read files and count words, then you don't need this Data class: just read some files and count the words.

Comment: To down-voters: please also explain why, or nobody is any the wiser.

Comment: Thanks, but each word will have its own frequency, while in Map<String, Integer> I can just store one frequency for whole string. In addition, I also need IDF then how can I get IDF with this data structure?

Comment: My intent was that you would map each word to its frequency. Obviously you need to split strings up into words at some point. As for IDF, you've already told us how to calculate that.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating only one instance of `Data`. You probably want to do something more like:

```
    Data dt = new Data();
    dt.addData("abc.txt", "some contents", 2);
    map.put("1",dt);

    dt = new Data();
    dt.addData("w", "some more contents in second file", 3);
    map.put("2",dt);
```

Or better yet, change `Data` to take the properties in its constructor:

```
    map.put("1", new Data("abc.txt", "some contents", 2));
    map.put("2", new Data("w", "some more contents in second file", 3));
```

Comment: thanks, any idea how to store freq. in data class? I think I need value[] array to store different words freq. what do you think?

Comment: @user431276 To store different word frequencies you probably want a `Map<String, Integer>` in your `Data` class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your question is (see comments below your question), but there's a few things wrong with your code. `addData` is a misleading name for a method that *replaces* the data in the object. But the real problem is here:

```
  dt.addData("abc.txt", "some contents", 2);
  map.put("1",dt);
  dt.addData("w", "some more contents in second file", 3);
  map.put("2",dt);
```

This results in a map containing two entries, both of which refer to the *same* `Data` object, which will contain the values from the last call to `addData`. Change `addData` to be a constructor:

```
public Data(String fileName, String fileText, float value) {
```

Then change your map code to this:

```
map.put("1", new Data("abc.txt", "some contents", 2));
map.put("2", new Data("w", "some more contents in second file", 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are expecting to see the Data string representation.

When you invoke println over any object ( including the map )  the system invokes [Object.toString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

In the case of the map, the toString method returns the content of the map, in a format similar to this:

```
{ key = value, key2, value2 }
```

That is, print the key,value pairs it has.

Now, the key and value are objects too, so their own `toString()` method is invoked. For a string the value is it self. But, in the case of `Data`, since you haven't supplied your own implementation, you'll get default's which is  `object fully qualified name @ object.hashCode()`   So you are probably getting something like:

```
 { 1 = Data@0xa6f2be, 2 = Data@0xa6f2be }
```

To change this you have to override the `toString()` method:

```
 class Data { 
  ... etc. etc. 
     public String toString() { 
       // return something meaningful like:
       return String.format( "Data( fileName = %s, fileText = %s, etc ", this.fileName, this.fileText );
     }
  }
```

As for the second question, you'll do it *basically* the same way as you would in C. Perhaps you should create a `calculate()` method that [opens the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file), and start the counting. Probably this deserve its own question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Where should I call calculate method? In data class or in main class? I am sorry I belong to old structure based school. I can calculate words as I read file and calculate TF but what about IDF? How do I calculate IDF? Should I create another field in Data class to store IDF values or what? If you want I can post another question separately...

Comment: Exactly in the same place as you would call in C `calucalte( thisStruct )`  :)  I would call it in main. As for IDF

Comment: ahh thanks :) I thaught may be there is another OOP myth to declare such functions. Thanks for your help. Do you have any idea how to use array in my Data class? I have to store freq. for each word and now I am using one float that can only store one word's freq. Any idea how to do it? I can declare array of float in Data class but I don't know how to use it :p. In addition, how can I get specific value from Data class object? For example calling getFileName to get only 1 class name???